# How to apply styles to a function in React js using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, in that I have a button when I click the button then I have to apply margin-bottom: 100px. I am trying to achieve this but it is showing some error so help me to solve this error.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)

  const applyStyles = () => {
    style={
      marginBottom: '100px'
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
             <button onClick={applyStyles} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
          </div>
          <div className='second'>
            <div className='box'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You don't set state manually in React, you use the state setting function (in this case `setStyle`). You should do some basic React tutorials about state and state management, it's a vital fundamental

Comment: Manage the toggle state in the onclick and then conditionally set the style prop on the button based on the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)

  const applyStyles = () => {
    setStyle({
      marginBottom: '100px'
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
             <button onClick={applyStyles} style={style} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
          </div>
          <div className='second'>
            <div className='box'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It is not the best practice though. You should look at higher order components like [withStyles](https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-styles).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not match with react behavior.
Just do like this. Have two css classes

```
.btn-clicked {
  margin-bottom: '100px'
}
```

In the JSX

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

  const applyStyles = () => {
    style={
      marginBottom: '100px'
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
             <button onClick={() => setClicked(true)} className={`btn btn-primary ${clicked ? 'btn-clicked': ''}`}>Click here</button>
          </div>
          <div className='second'>
            <div className='box'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```